# SharePoint calculated Column Queries

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column

I have a list with a column  [Employee Name].

[Employee Name] can have following possibilities:

For example:

1. Aaron Hawkins
2. Abdou Aziz Tebda
3. Abdoul Kader Rasac Tiendrebegog

On all 3 cases i want to extract firstname, lastname and middlename 
 and put it as lastname middlename firstname

So after change Above example should show up as:

1. Hawkins Aaron
2. Tebda Aziz Abdou
3. Tiendrebegog Kader Rasac Abdoul

I was able to extract firstname using FIND and Left Funcation

as below

=Left([Employee Name],FIND(" ",[Employee Name]))

=Left(Aaron Hawkins,6)
=Aaron

Now how do i extract lastname and middlename so that i can concatenate new values together to get desired result.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

First Name:

```
=LEFT([Employee Name],INT(FIND(" ",[Employee Name])-1))
```

Last Name:

```
=RIGHT([Employee Name],LEN([Employee Name])-INT(FIND(" ",[Employee Name],2)))
```

Middle Name:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT([Employee Name],INT(FIND(" ",[Employee Name])-1)),INT(FIND(" ",RIGHT([Employee Name],INT(FIND(" ",[Employee Name])-1)))-1))
```

Comment: Are the ``INT`` required?  FIND returns a Number

Comment: After finding the index of a blank space, for getting the first name need to subtract 1 from the index so just for proper conversion it is used.

Comment: SharePoint is the most lenient application out there on Types. It does all those conversions for you; so ``"1"  + 1``  is 2 for SharePoint . So you can shorten all those formulas.  ``"1+1"`` will output the String ``"1+1"`` and ``"1+1"+1`` or ``INT("1+1")`` will output an error.. because even SharePoint can't make an Integer of ``"1+1"``